# if no database entries

Tags: php, mysql

I am grabbing entries from a database and displaying them on my web page like so:

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM posts order by id desc") or die(mysql_error()); 
if (!$query) {
    die('MySQL error'); 
} else {
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)):
    // HTML stuff with <?php echo $row['title']; ?>
endwhile; }
```

How can I write a if statement to echo "Nothing Found" if there are no entries to get? So basically, if the query does its thing and finds nothing, how can I echo some sort of "error message"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use:

```
if (mysql_num_rows($query) > 0) {
    // while here
} else {
    // error output here
}
```

Answer (score 6):

```
if (mysql_num_rows($result) > 0) {
    Do something;
}
else {
    No results;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I like grabbing num_rows myself for checks like this.

```
$num_rows = mysql_num_rows($query)
if($num_rows == 0)
{
    echo "Nothing found";
}
else
{
    ....
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM posts order by id desc") or die(mysql_error()); 
if (!$query) {
    die('MySQL error'); 
} else if (mysql_num_rows($query) == 0){
     echo "Nothing Found";
} else {
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)):
    // HTML stuff with <?php echo $row['title']; ?>
endwhile; }
```

The link to the php API that explains the function is http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-num-rows.php.